# Paragraph type can't delete individual items

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I use [Paragraph module](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) `Version: 8.x-1.5`. Somehow I can't delete individual items anymore?

Is there a settings somewhere I missed?[image]

Comment: Is that link defininetly a paragraph field? It looks like a link field that's set to allow unlimited items. Which wouldnt have the delete button as it just keep appending one onto the end

Comment: @LeighMason yes it's a paragraph field thats set to allow unlimited items. But is it not possible to have the delete button there?

Comment: If you inspect element do you see the remove button?

Comment: No. Only the order-selectbox is set to display: none;

Comment: I have same issue , cannot delete single item from collection , in my case it's media entity reference field so i can't delete one of them -.-

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and also have a link field set to unlimited. I don't see a remove button. Evidently there is a patch in progress for this specific issue. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1038316